# Derive status from a 24 value integer list representing 24 hours

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm trying to come up with a way to represent 3 states of availability I have for an item within a single python object if possible.

I would like to try to maintain a consistent state of combined (24hours) along with status of the item (unavailable, available and booked)

Currently, I have to pull a json field with a schedule, any possible reservations and represent the availability and unavailability for the next 24 hours.

first thought was to do a list with the 3 status in it representing 24 hours.

## 24 hour clock with status in it

```
hours = [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] # example
```

0 being not available,
1 being available (due to current time is within schedule)
2 being booked and not available

```
# postgres json field of a single schedule cannot be altered 

schedule = {
    'availability': {
        'mon': { 'start': '01:00:00', 'end': '13:00:00'},
        'tue': { 'start': '01:00:00', 'end': '13:00:00'},
        'wed': { 'start': '01:00:00', 'end': '13:00:00'},
        'thu': { 'start': '01:00:00', 'end': '13:00:00'},
        'fri': { 'start': '01:00:00', 'end': '13:00:00'},
        'sat': { 'start': '01:00:00', 'end': '13:00:00'},
        'sun': { 'start': '01:00:00', 'end': '13:00:00'},
    }
}

# example booking

booking_today_start = datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 1, 1, 0, 0) # postgres date field
booking_today_end = datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 1, 10, 0, 0) # postgres date field
```

I'm finding it difficult with this kind of idea to update the list because the list may have to be shifted and recalculated every hour to maintain its state and it makes it error prone

Is there a better way to represent this kind of status within a python data structure given that I have to combine these three postgres fields into a usable object to represent the state of both hours and availability 3 different ways. Would it be better to scrap the json field and go with date fields for each day and try to do it in postgres rather than python? Anyone who might have had to tackle this before, I would appreciate any tips or even direction to go in, or how I might approach it better, Thanks!

```
class User(SurrogatePK, Model):

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    # Relationships.
    reservations = db.relationship('Reservation', backref='guest', uselist=False)

    addresses = db.relationship('Properties', backref='host', uselist=False)

    # other user props below

class Property(SurrogatePK, Model):
    __tablename__ = 'addresses'

    # relationships Property.host > User
    host_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id',
                                                  onupdate='CASCADE',
                                                  ondelete='CASCADE'),
                                                  index=True, nullable=False)
    reservations = db.relationship('Reservation',
                                    backref='address_property', uselist=False)
    #schedule
    schedule = Column(JSON, nullable=True)
    avail_type = Column(db.Unicode(50), nullable=True) # hourly etc
    is_avail = Column(db.Boolean(), default=True)

class Reservation(SurrogatePK, Model):
    __tablename__ =  'reservations'

    # relationships
    # Reservation.guest > User
    guest_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('users.id',
                                    onupdate='CASCADE', ondelete='CASCADE'),
                                    nullable=False)
    address_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('addresses.id', onupdate='CASCADE',
                                    ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)

    status = db.Column(db.Enum('pending', 'confirmed', 'rejected',
        name='reservation_status_enum'), default='confirmed')

    reserve_start = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    reserve_end = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    @classmethod
    def _time_in_range(self, x):
        if self.reserve_start <= self.reserve_end:
            return self.reserve_start <= x <= self.reserve_end
        else:
            return self.start <= x or x <= self.reserve_end
```

Comment: Why does it have to be a single object?

Comment: it doesn't have to be but it's to be pushed down to a client which can then easily read it and display the availability for the day based on the schedule/current reservations and hours. The hope was to do this kind of operation in the background and keep a consistent state for a lot of items this way. As opposed to doing it within large many hundred item queries live on the fly.

Comment: It sounds like you're writing an API endpoint for an availability calendar. In that case, you should be able to skip the Python object and have Postgres directly produce JSON appropriate to the API call in a single query. If you show us the schema we can work out some example queries. I suspect the schema is abusing JSONB columns to avoid thinking about the table design.

Comment: I am doing an API resource as you mentioned and it is putting out json specifically with availability attached to each item, I couldn't paste in the whole thing as it's all too long but is that enough to give an idea? Thanks for taking a look. I think I know where you are going but I have no idea where to begin query wise to get what you are describing. SQLalchemy is in use here which may limit me a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is nice because its very fast to find out "is this available at this particular hour" but it cannot support a range like 17:30 - 20:45 and you have to do a bit of extra calculation to ask "is it available at 04:15?"

Instead, I'd suggest doing the same thing as the Postgres database does: store the start and end time per day of week. Use `datetime.time` objects. Comparison is simple, choose the appropriate day of week, and check that `start_time <= time && time <= end_time`.

Comment: Thanks! ok, I had a hunch it was going to go that way. I have this exact kind of idea you recommended in use and it's great. Currently this idea will get me "is the item available for the current time or a time range I give it", but doesn't quite represent it's availability or unavailability for the rest of the hours. I'm looking for a way to represent that status per hour. Like a calendar with x's and checks on it but hours. Seems like pg is going to be the way to go so i'll go in that direction and try to build it with fields and query per hour and do it that way as I think you suggest.